Does the posted date in SSRN change if you upload a new version?
I have decided to upload a paper I wrote to SSRN, in part because I want the date in which the paper was uploaded to be publicly available. However, SSRN allows you to upload new versions of your paper. If you do so, does the posted date of the preprint change or remains the same?

The posted date remains, even if you upload a subsequent version. If you update the preprint, it will add a "last revised" date in addition to the "(originally) posted" date. Here is an example where you can see that functionality in action (also, it's a very cool paper I use when I teach stats):
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1592456
So, feel free to update your paper, without fear that the original date info will be lost. Assuming the new version is an improvement, your readers will appreciate it!
